# Проблема с GitHub?

Tags: github

После внесения коммита в реозиторий появилаь надпись - "Fetching latest commit…" 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А проект в Visual Studio -пишет, что "ожидает изминений" - что делать? и из-за чего это?

Comment: может быть гитхаб призадумался. Или Вы попытались закоммитить пару гигабайт файл (или кто то подобное запушил, а Вы теперь пулите). Этот список можно продолжать долго.

Comment: само пройдет или нужно что-то делать?

Comment: а кто его знает. Я бы подождал с полчасика, перезагрузил комп.  Если не пройдет - писать в саппорт гитхаба.

Comment: понял, спасибо!